# Beta app is shown in the browser but not in Google Play?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I've published a beta of my app in Google Play.

I can see it with my smartphone and I can install it with a different account from the developer account (just to be sure).

Now I try the same with an 'old' tablet (Android 7.0, Google Play 6.1.12) and if I click on the link to the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infinitymundi.anima

it tells me 'element not found':

[image]

if I try to cut and paste the link in the browser it shows the app:

[image]

It even shows the Install button, but if I click it gives me 'element not found' again.

My app is built with Unity and it's compatible with Android 6.0+ (I deployed the same app in this tablet with Unity and it worked).

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to update Google Play Services on your device? Alternatively, you can repeat the very same steps on a simulator.

Comment: @AdrianoDiGiovanni Thanks, it seems it's a problem with Google Play (too old). I'm unable to update id though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that you need to download an unofficial google play services update from here https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/ and it worked.

Maybe this is strictly related to my tablet model (a Xiaomi).

It will be useful for others, I think.